# how to get the firstname and email from a JSON response

Tags: javascript, json

```
{
  "userId": 1,
  "userName": "username",
  "firstName": "firstname",
  "lastName": "lname",
  "middleInitial": null,
  "email": "nsk@gmail.com",
  "dob": -250666200000,
  "phoneNo": 2066628405,
  "workPhone": null,
  "mobileNo": 2036321543,
  "status": null,
  "address": null,
  "group": null
}
```

Comment: Please give more details about this, you are posting without context.

Comment: The question has all the context it needs. There is a json object and the user wants to fetch some of the values inside it.

Comment: @IdanAdar Except there is no such thing as a "JSON object". There are JavaScript objects, and there is JSON represented as strings. What the OP has shown is a plain old JS object.

Comment: i get the above json response from the restfull web  service. i use the HTTP-adapters. i need to print the first name and email in the front page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i dont know what is the json.

Is it a response from a ajax or is it on variable on JavaScript page. i consider it as a variable so;

```
var myjson={
  "userId": 1,
  "userName": "username",
  "firstName": "firstname",
  "lastName": "lname",
  "middleInitial": null,
  "email": "nsk@gmail.com",
  "dob": -250666200000,
  "phoneNo": 2066628405,
  "workPhone": null,
  "mobileNo": 2036321543,
  "status": null,
  "address": null,
  "group": null
}
```

you can get firstname and last name by simply call as

```
myjson.firstName;
```

and

```
myjson.email;
```

wherever you required. You need to study more about JSON and its usage :

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json.asp
and parser online
http://pro.jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0):

I will answer your question with a bit of code. I am assuming that you are using WLResourceRequest but no matter what your returned response is going to look the same. We return the response as a JSON object with probably some key values that you do not care about.

The key that you are interested in is responseJSON which is a JSON object. This is where your adapter information is going to be. To access that value see the onResponseSuccess message below.

Looking at your question the object that you are expecting back is:

```
{
  "userId": 1,
  "userName": "username",
  "firstName": "firstname",
  "lastName": "lname",
  "middleInitial": null,
  "email": "nsk@gmail.com",
  "dob": -250666200000,
  "phoneNo": 2066628405,
  "workPhone": null,
  "mobileNo": 2036321543,
  "status": null,
  "address": null,
  "group": null
}

var resourceRequest = new WLResourceRequest(
      "adapter/path",
      WLResourceRequest.GET
);

resourceRequest.send().then(
      this.onResponseSuccess,
      this.onResponseFailure
);

onResponseSuccess(response) {
   var <value> = response.responseJSON.<key>
}
```

key and value are your key value pairs in your JSON object. 
Your response object is going to look like

```
response : {
    status : 200,
    resonseText : "some long straing that is JSON stringified",
    responseJSON: {
       "userId" : 1,
       "username": "username",
       ...
       "group": null
    }
}
```

To access "userId" you are going to do response.responseJSON.userId

Answer (score -1):

If the response is a string you can parse the response using

var jsondata = JSON.parse(res);

you can get any parameter using jsondata.firstname or jsondata.email